# error TS5083: Cannot read file '/tsconfig.json'

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run the command "tsc --build" when running "docker compose up --build" so it can run that command when creating the Docker container.

The thing is I am getting always an error:

[image]

I have been reading about it and I am not importing in my code anything outside the "rootdir"... so I have no idea why those packages are there...

I am not sure if removing the rootdir option from tsconfig file is a good idea or it would cause an error afterwards in my app...

Any ideas?

Comment: before you run `npm run build` you only copy `package*.json` to your image. So there is no `tsconfig.json` in your image ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy your `tsconfig.json` to your Docker image.

Add the following after line 5:

`COPY tsconfig.json ./`

Notes:

- You probably need to also copy the nodemon.json
- At the line 10 you copy all the current directory to your image, ensure your `.dockerignore` file contain a rule to exclude the node_modules/, dist/ folders.

Comment: Now I am getting another different errors:

error TS5055: Cannot write file '/opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn.js' because it would overwrite input file.

error TS6059: File '/opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

And many more similar

Comment: I have edited my first question to update the screenshots

Comment: Please create a new question, don't update your original question to a different when you have an different problem.